# Reusing a username

Tags: username

I created an account on Ubuntu One but deleted it. I made another account with a different email and wanted to use the same username as the account I deleted, but it said it was still in use. When I tried to sign into the deleted account it didn't work. Is the username gone forever?

Comment: You should ask this by e-mail to `isd-support@canonical.com` which is provided in the [FAQ](https://login.ubuntu.com/+faq).